# ASP.net 4.0 Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I wrote this simple program in ASP.net 4.0:

```
Dim x, y
Dim xcircle() As Double = New Double(360) {}
Dim ycircle() As Double = New Double(360) {}
For t = 0 To 360 Step 1
    x = Math.Cos(t * Math.PI / 180)
    y = Math.Sin(t * Math.PI / 180)
    xcircle(t) = x
    ycircle(t) = y
Next t
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.DataBindXY(xcircle, ycircle)
```

I keep getting this error:

> System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd.

Here is my web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
  </appSettings>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
  </httpHandlers>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: post the stack trace. did you see exactly where the error is in your debugger? What line of code did it hit? did you try the same thing in a simple winforms app? most likely you are using the Chart object incorrectly in some way and an exception is thrown by it.

Comment: I have went thru Toggle Breakpoint and Step Into but could not find a stack trace.  How do you do that?  This error only occurs in my websites with Charts.

Comment: the stack trace is what is given to you when there is an exception. Also look at the output window when the exception is thrown - it should spit it all out there.